# Can I ask a question about problems with my IDE on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, scope

I'm having a problem with my Netbeans IDE and I'm not sure if I can ask about it on Stack Overflow.

Can I ask question about problems with my IDE on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, they are on topic on Stack Overflow.

As per the [What is on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page:

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm
- **software tools commonly used by programmers**
- practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development

(emphasis mine)

There are lots of IDE questions throughout SO in various paradigms, so there's lots of precedence for it.

There are even [332 questions tagged with both IDE and Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide+netbeans) (and most of them are open).

Comment: That said, some questions about IDEs are perhaps off topic. Like "how do I install the IDE", rather than "how do I use the IDE to perform operation X"

Answer (score 2):

The description of [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at stack overflow is

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people
>   who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow
>   questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question
>   generally covers…
>
> ```
>     a specific programming problem
>     a software algorithm
>     software tools commonly used by programmers
>     practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development
> ```

This fits squarely in software tools commonly used by programmers